# Invoke-WebRequest Proxy Bypass

Tags: powershell, proxy, webrequest

**How to bypass the default proxy in Windows while accessing a locally accessible URL?**

By default the Invoke-WebRequest powershell cmdlet is using the default proxy server. In my setup the proxy allows only certain URLs and the locally accessible URL is not in that list.

Is there a way to bypass the proxy? I can add the URL to the proxy allowed list but I don't want to do that.

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically bypass proxy for local addresses and even return the old bypass list after you are done.

My function [proxy](https://github.com/majkinetor/posh/blob/master/MM_Network/Update-Proxy.ps1) will let you do that. Add your domain or server name or its IP address to override list:

```
   $p = proxy
   $p.Override += "*.domain.com" 
   $p | proxy
   Invoke-WebRequest ...
   #you could return old override here.
```

Otherwise, I think this should work:

```
 $proxy = new-object System.Net.WebProxy
 Invoke-WebRequest -Proxy $proxy ...
```

Comment: Will it break the applications that depend on the proxy while this is running? It didn't look so.

Comment: No , the later call is local only.