# Invoke-RestMethod works on cable but not on Wifi

Tags: powershell, curl, networking, windows-terminal, invoke-restmethod

**When connected on Wifi:**

```
PS C:\Users\Julio> Invoke-RestMethod juliobs.com
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod juliobs.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

**When connected on Cable:**

```
PS C:\Users\Julio> Invoke-RestMethod juliobs.com
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Last Published: April 6, 2023 --><html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

...
```

Both connections are to the same router using the same DNS config.
`curl` from `cmd.exe` or `WSL` work fine on wifi.

The same error happened in one other Wifi network.

Tested with PowerShell 5.1 (on Windows Terminal 1.16 and Windows PowerShell ISE)

```
PS C:\Users\Julio> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      22621  963
```

The error "The underlying connection was closed" is usually related to TLS, but this does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: TLS when fails is a timeout error message which indicates the connection did not complete.  I've seen similar errors when the the Wifi was using IPV6 and local was using IPV4.  I would try to bypass the proxy.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463380/powershell-v5-1-invoke-restmethod-and-bypass-proxy?force_isolation=true